# Command to find the source package of a binary?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages

I know there's a `which` command, that echoes the full name of a binary (e.g. `which sh`). However, I'm fairly sure there's a command that echoes the package that provides a particular binary. Is there such a command? If so, what is it? I'd like to be able to run this:

`commandName ls`

and get

`coreutils`

for example.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the [`dpkg -S` command](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/65/query-using-debian-packaging-manager/) (also see [frequently used options for dpkg](http://www.linuxconfig.org/frequently-used-options-for-debian-dpkg-command)).

Comment: Thank you! `dpkg -S \`which COMMANDHERE\`` worked for me.

Comment: Gentoo: qfile <name>

Comment: `dpkg -S` finds the name of the binary package name, which can differ from the name of the source (code) package.

Comment: Just for completeness, `-S` is the short form of the `--search` option, which is actually an option to the `dpkg-query` command (but plain `dpkg` works too)

Comment: like @waldyrious mentioned, this gets you the *binary* package that corresponds to a *file*. This does **NOT** tell you the *source* package corresponding to a *binary* package. So while accurate, this isn't the answer you're looking for if you're trying to find the source package corresponding to a binary package.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to find files in a package that you haven't installed, use **apt-file**

```
apt-get install -y apt-file
apt-file update
```

Then, to find something:

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/file
```

or

```
apt-find search file
```

Where "file" is the name of whatever you're searching for.

If you don't feel like going through this on every debian system, you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
which apt-get >/dev/null || { echo apt-get not found >&2; exit 1; }
which apt-file >/dev/null || { apt-get install -y apt-file;  apt-file update; }
unset i; IFS=$'\x0a'; select i in $( apt-file search "/$@" ); do 
    test -n "$i" || break; apt-get install "${i%% *}"; done
```

I just whipped that up then, but it seems to work well.

*Note: "dpkg -S" only finds things that you've already installed.*

Comment: Using the `-y` parameter is dangerous, it could say yes to any number of things. In the script it might be fine, but the first command should really read `apt-get install apt-file` without the `-y`as you can't know what the user's system looks like.

Comment: @jmiserez that's a value judgement, and purely subjective opinion that should not be applied as a fits-all rule.  `apt-get install -y linux-*` would be extremely bad, `apt-get install -y fortune` is quite different.  Please also not that these are being used in a `bash/sh script` context beneath, where superfluous user confirmation is end-of-game.

Comment: For arch based systems, check out this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/in-arch-linux-how-can-i-find-out-which-package-to-install-that-will-contain-file). `pkgfile` or `pacman -F` options are the ones I tested.
I have added this comment because a google search brought me here instead of in the other one.